# Laravel - create model, controller and migration in single artisan command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I can create a model and resource controller (binded to model) with the following command

```
php artisan make:controller TodoController --resource --model=Todo
```

I want to also create a migration with the above command, is it possible?

Comment: I think in this case the flag --resource is not needed. --model is enough.

Answer (score 642, accepted):

You can do it if you start from the model

```
php artisan make:model Todo -mcr
```

if you run `php artisan make:model --help` you can see all the available options

> -m, --migration       Create a new migration file for the model.
>     -c, --controller      Create a new controller for the model.
>       -r, --resource        Indicates if the generated controller should be a resource controller

**Update**

As mentioned in the comments by @arun in newer versions of laravel > 5.6 it is possible to run following command:

```
php artisan make:model Todo -a
```

> -a, --all             Generate a migration, factory, and resource
>   controller for the model

Comment: Now we can use `php artisan make:model Todo -a` to create model, migration, resource controller and `factory`

Comment: why, for example, the method `show` param is the model object when creating with `make:model -mcr` vs `make:controller --resource` the method `show` param is `$id`

Comment: @Cr1xus Because in the second command you need to specify which Resource model you want to use,  in the first command the -r flag knows the correct model because we just made that model.

Comment: when I use this command, why it doesnt creates ModelResource.php in app/http/resources directory ?

Comment: @tyasird Resource means that your controllers will be preloaded with auto-injected model. This does not mean the api-resources

Answer (score 65):

**Updated**

Laravel 6 or Later

Through the model

To Generate a migration, seeder, factory and resource controller for the model

```
php artisan make:model Todo -a
```

Or

```
php artisan make:model Todo -all
```

***Other Options***

**-c, --controller**      Create a new controller for the model

**-f, --factory**         Create a new factory for the model

**--force**           Create the class even if the model already exists

**-m, --migration**       Create a new migration file for the model

**-s, --seed**            Create a new seeder file for the model

**-p, --pivot**           Indicates if the generated model should be a custom intermediate table model

**-r, --resource**        Indicates if the generated controller should be a resource controller

**For More Help**

```
php artisan make:model Todo -help
```

Hope Newbies will get help.

Comment: -all wont work, probably --all

Answer (score 34):

You can do it with the following command:

```
php artisan make:model post -mcr
```

Brief :

-m, to create migration

-c to create controller

-r to specify the controller has resource

Answer (score 32):

You can make **model** + **migration** + **controller**, all in one line, using this command:

```
php artisan make:model --migration --controller test
```

Short version: `php artisan make:model -mc test`

**Output :-**

> Model created successfully.
>
> Created Migration:2018_03_10_002331_create_tests_table
>
> Controller created successfully.

---

If you need to perform all **CRUD** operations in the **controller** then use this command:

```
php artisan make:model --migration --controller test --resource
```

Short version: `php artisan make:model -mc test --resource`

Comment: please use php artisan make:model --migration --controller --resource Test .

Comment: bro i create first and then post this . actually i use your given command and add --resource at end and this work please check from you end . I am useing laravel 5.4 . may lower version of laravel not support . @Udhav

Comment: I installed fresh Laravel, Your suggestion code is working, thank you @Affan :)

Answer (score 9):

```
php artisan make:model PurchaseRequest -crm
```

The Result is

```
Model created successfully.
Created Migration: 2018_11_11_011541_create_purchase_requests_table
Controller created successfully.
```

Just use **-crm** instead of -mcr

Comment: Why should we use -crm instead of -mcr

Answer (score 8):

php artisan make:model Author -cfmsr

-c, --controller Create a new controller for the model

-f, --factory Create a new factory for the model

-m, --migration Create a new migration file for the model

-s, --seed Create a new seeder file for the model

-r, --resource Indicates if the generated controller should be a resource controller

Answer (score 5):

Laravel 5.4 You can use

```
 php artisan make:model --migration --controller --resource Test
```

This will create 
1) Model
2) controller with default resource function
3) Migration file

And Got Answer

Model created successfully.

Created Migration: 2018_04_30_055346_create_tests_table

Controller created successfully.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Laravel as an only API add `--api` option:

```sh
php artisan make:model Post -a --api
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `php artisan make:model Todo -a` to create model, migration, resource controller and factory

Comment: are you still working in velan?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add --resource flag just type the following and laravel will create the whole desired resources

```
 php artisan make:controller TodoController --model=todo
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using long command like

```
php artisan make:model <Model Name> --migration --controller --resource
```

for ***make migration, model and controller***, you may use even shorter as -mcr.

```
php artisan make:model <Model Name> -mcr
```

For more [***MOST USEFUL LARAVEL ARTISAN MAKE COMMANDS LISTS***](https://3gtechsol.com/blog/most-useful-laravel-artisan-make-commands-lists-with-parameters)

Comment: php artisan make:model <Model Name> --migration --controller --resource
has worked for me thanks

Answer (score 2):

To make mode, controllers with resources, You can type CMD as follows :

```
 php artisan make:model Todo -mcr
```

or you can check by typing

```
php artisan help make:model
```

where you can get all the ideas

Answer (score 2):

You can use -m -c -r to make migration, model and controller.

```
php artisan make:model Post -m -c -r
```

Answer (score 1):

To make all 3: **Model, Controller & Migration Schema of table**

write in your console: `php artisan make:model NameOfYourModel -mcr`

Answer (score 1):

How I was doing it until now:

```
php artisan make:model Customer
php artisan make:controller CustomersController --resource
```

Apparently, there’s a quicker way:

```
php artisan make:controller CustomersController --model=Customer
```

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan make:model modelname -mcr`
to create model. Here `-mcr` stands for migrations components and resourses