# how to create all three file in laravel (controller, model and database migrated file) with one command

Tags: php, laravel

## php artisan make:model -mcr Task

Model created successfully.
Created Migration: 2018_08_16_082225_create_tasks_table
Controller created successfully.

You will get all file in one command.

Comment: I tried in laravel 5.5 and above version.

Comment: Reference this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187735/laravel-5-4-create-model-controller-and-migration-in-single-artisan-command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - create model, controller and migration in single artisan command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187735/laravel-create-model-controller-and-migration-in-single-artisan-command)

Answer (score 5):

The below Command will create the model, Controller, Factory, migration and Seeder.

```
php artisan make:model ModelName -a
```

**-a stands for all (Model, controller, factory, Migration and Seeder)**

***Note: The above command will work successfully in Laravel 5.5 or > versions***

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command for create **model** and **controller** and **migration** at same time:( You can use `--migration` Instead of `-m` and you can use `--controller` Instead of `-c`)

```
php artisan make:model MODEL_NAME -c -m
```

or you can use for create **model** , **controller** ,**migration** and **factory** at same time ( Youc can use `--all` Instead of `-a`):

```
php artisan make:model MODEL_NAME -a
```

Answer (score 0):

php artisan make:model -mcr Task

You will get all file in one command.

Answer (score 0):

you can make model + migration + controller, all in one line, reference this link

[Laravel 5.4 create model, controller and migration in single artisan command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187735/laravel-5-4-create-model-controller-and-migration-in-single-artisan-command)